# Get text from a div using beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract from the following html code only the placename using python and bs4.

```
<div class="results-list" id="theaterlist">
 <table>
  <tr class="trspacer">
   <td>
    <a href="theater.aspx?id=4000642">
     <h2 class="placename">
      Hyde Park
      <span class="boldelement">
      Richmond Avenue 56 ls61bz
      </span>
     </h2>
    </a>
```

I m using the following code but i get the address too.

```
mydivs = soup.find("div", {"id": "theaterlist"})
lis = mydivs.select("a[href*=theater.aspx]")
for x in lis:
    theater = x.find('h2', class_='placename')
    print theater.text
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For getting the text only for the element (not child elements) you can use `.find(text=True)`:

```
data = """
<div class="results-list" id="theaterlist">
 <table>
  <tr class="trspacer">
   <td>
    <a href="theater.aspx?id=4000642">
     <h2 class="placename">
      Hyde Park
      <span class="boldelement">
      Richmond Avenue 56 ls61bz
      </span>
     </h2>
    </a>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('h2').find(text=True).strip())
```

Prints:

```
Hyde Park
```

Comment: thank you, for your quick response. If i want to take only the child element's text how should i adapt the code?

Comment: @sotokan80 If you know that h2 tag has one span (like in example), you can do soup.find('h2').contents[1].text.strip(). This returns "Richmond Avenue 56 ls61bz".

Answer (score 0):

```
soup.find("div", {"id": "theaterlist"}).find('h2', class_='placename').text.strip()
# 'Hyde Park\n      \n      Richmond Avenue 56 ls61bz'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for x in soup.select("a[href*=theater.aspx]"):
    theater = x.find('h2', class_='placename')
    print(theater.contents[0].strip())
```